# In React ES6, is it safe to change an HTML element's tag by creating a React element from a property turned string?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is it safe to change an HTML element's tag by creating a React element from a property turned string?

Example:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

const Copy = ({ element, title, description }) => {
    const Element = `${element}`;
    return (
        <div className="copy">
            {title &&
                <Element className="title">{title}</Element>
            }
            {description &&
                <p className="description">{description}</p>
            }
        </div>
    );
};

Copy.propTypes = {
    element: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    description: PropTypes.string,
};

Copy.defaultProps = {
    element: 'h1';
    title: null,
    description: null,
};

export default Copy;
```

I found this method of doing this from another post somewhere but did not see any information regarding whether it is safe to do or not.

Also, is this (below) the correct and only way to write this?

```
const Element = `${element}`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this approach. If you try to set the `element` prop to something like `<script>alert('script injection')</script>`, you'll only see an `Invalid tag` exception, no actual script injection will happen.

The `element` property is of type `string` as defined by `propTypes`, so this

```
const Element = `${element}`;
```

is equal to this

```
const Element = element;
```

since

```
`${element}` === element
```

Comment: When I first tried `const Element = element;` it did not work for me, possibly due to a typo, but it definitely works now, thanks! I knew there was a better, simpler way to write it. Also, thanks for the explanation regarding the safety of this approach.

Comment: Pedantically, in the general case, `\`${element}` === element.toString()`. But in the cases of strings, then yes, both forms are equivalent. Just a not for readers not to assume full equivalence. This answer only briefly mentions that.